# See type of Garbage Collector in Java Mission Control

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jmc

How to see type of Garbage Collector in Java Mission Control?

I investigated all tabs including MBeans Browser, but didn't find the type of GC. I can only suppose it by memory regions enumerated on the Memory tab.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JMC doens't show Garbage Collector type. So I set GC type explicitly and looked at the `Memory` tab on the `Active Memory Pools` section.

---

GC type: `Garbarge-First (G1)`

JVM option: `-XX:+UseG1GC`

Poll names: `G1 Eden Space`, `G1 Old Gen`, `G1 Servivor Space`

---

GC type: `Parallel`

JVM option: `-XX:+UseParallelGC`

Poll names: `PS Eden Space`, `PS Old Gen`, `PS Servivor Space`

---

GC type: `Concurrent Mark Sweep (CMS)`

JVM option: `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Poll names: `Par Eden Space`, `CMS Old Gen`, `Par Servivor Space`

---

...to be continued

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Memory` tab and then `GC Configuration` (Bottom of the window) you will see the entire gc config here including GC Types, Parallel GC Threads, Concurrent GC Threads etc., The screenshot is fom JMC 5.5.0

[image]

Comment: Arun, thanks for answer! Do you use Java Mission Control (it's included in JDK like VisualVM)? Names of tabs are different from mine (I use JDK 8). There is no "GC Configuration" tab.

Comment: I found you use Flight Recorder. But it's a commercial feature. So it may be unavailable.

Comment: @AleksYa _"The Java Flight Recorder (JFR) is a commercial feature. You can use it for free on developer desktops/laptops, and for evaluation purposes in test, development, and production environments. However, to enable JFR on a production server, you require a commercial license. Using JMC UI for other purposes on the JDK does not require a commercial license."_ 
Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr002.html 
So if you want to use it on a production machine you will need a license.